# How to Create Hours xAxis

Tags: swift, ios-charts, swiftcharts

I read all the relevant issues, and also the wiki.
I'm trying to put Hours on the X - Axis, and want to show minutes when dragging the tracer.
For Example - making points of 10:00, 09:00, 08:00.... and when dragging the tracer between them show the exact value for example 10:22 on the tracer label.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: This might help https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: I read everything there. Didn't found a good explanation